# VS2010 Last Session Debugging Value

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010

This is nice feature for debugging. However, in normal edit mode, I need to keep my mouse cursor on the pin icon to display the info. Is there any way to keep the info display while mouse cursor move away? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for pinned data tips (new to Visual Studio 2010).  Try the following

- Hover over a value with the mouse and the debugger data tip will show up
- On the right side of the tip is a push pin
- Click on that
- This will pin the data tip to the editor and you can move your mouse elsewhere

Pinned data tips are preserved between debugging sessions and you do not need to have your mouse ever them to see their values.

Here's a nice tutorial on them

- http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VS2010DataTips.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am actually talking about 'Last Value Display' which the debug info left after leaving debug mode. And looks like only mouse over can display the info. Is there any way to leave the info display after move away the mouse cursor on the pin?

Comment: @Stan, I'm sill not sure what you mean by Last Value Display.  Can you elaborate or post a link to the feature?

Comment: please go to http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/21/vs-2010-debugger-improvements-breakpoints-datatips-import-export.aspx   Look for this paragraph "Hovering your mouse over a pinned DataTip will cause it to display on the screen."

Comment: @Stan, I see what you're saying now.  Unfortunately no there is not a way to do this.  The data tips only show data on hover when you're not in a debugging session.